# Easier/cheaper way to add backgroundColor to TextButton LibGDX

Tags: scala, libgdx

I want to give TextButton a basic backgroundColor to distinguish it from a regular label.

Right now I am just drawing a filled rectangle behind the TextButton that I create with color (r,g,b,a) via a TextureRegion (in scala):

```
val pixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)
pixmap.setColor(r, g, b, a)
pixmap.fillRectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
val texture = new Texture(pixmap)
txr = new TextureRegion(texture)
pixmap.dispose
```

However, this means that every time I change the values of (r,g,b,a), a new texture is made, which is quite expensive. Therefore, I was wondering if there are better/easier ways to obtain a similar (visual) result.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly!

A. `textButton.setColor(color)` or `textButton.setColor(r,g,b,a)` is probably the simplest way to get what you want - it tints the existing textbutton texture to the specified color

B. If you do want to create a specific texture in-code, you can color that as well by wrapping the TextureRegion in a TextureRegionDrawable, e.g. `trd = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(pixmap)))`, and then you can tint *that* using `trd.tint(color)` - that way you create the pixmap once, and can tint it differently for every TextButton

Comment: Thank you. For me A is not working. As B concerns; trd.tint(Color) returns a drawable, how should I set the texture region (that I'm drawing) to the new drawable ?

Comment: Since textbutton is a Table, it has a setBackground() function. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081993/libgdx-scene2d-set-background-color-of-table